# Suppress Resharper Highlight

Tags: resharper

I'm trying to suppress highlights in ReSharper using ReSharper Platform (not ReSharper product).

Some context:

Exceptional is a ReSharper plugin, that highlights undocumented exceptions among other useful things. In some cases, these highlights are safe to be "suppressed".
Currently, suppressing comments aren't working: https://github.com/CSharpAnalyzers/ExceptionalReSharper/issues/37

I can suppress it by looking for the suppression comments (e.g.: // ReSharper disable once ExceptionNotDocumented) and simply not adding the highlight to the DefaultHighlightingConsumer, however, I'm not convinced that the platform doesn't have a simpler way to do this.

Is there a simple way to make ReSharper consider these suppressing comments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @citizenmatt I've finally come to the solution.

A change in the API (starting from 2016.1) has introduced a new HighlightConsumer implementation named FilteringHighlightConsumer. Using this implementation will consider all suppressing comments.

Here is the link to Matt's answer: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206559159-10-1-EAP-and-RegisterConfigurableSeverity?flash_digest=1939ba6f66e30d494edb8f0d6a902eab4b198342